# "MXNet Backend: Cannot automatically infer shape for convolution operator" in loss function

Tags: keras, mxnet

I'm calling keras.backend.conv2d in my loss function, and when I try to compile my model I get the following error:

> MXNet Backend: Cannot automatically infer shape for convolution operator. Please provide input shape. Given input shape - (None, None, None, None)

I know the shape of my input tensor so if there's some way to manually specify that I can do it, but I can't find such a thing anywhere in the keras api.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you simply need to add `input_shape` as an argument to `Conv2D`. For example:

```
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', input_shape=(256,256,3)))
```

If you need to call into backend, set x._keras_shape = (256, 256, 3) before calling keras.backend.conv2d().

Comment: That's the Conv2D layer, not keras.backend.conv2d. You can't use that in a loss function.

Comment: Can you call `x._keras_shape = (256, 256, 3)` before calling `keras.backend.conv2d()`, `x` being your input placeholder?